# Problem with enabling the Optimizing js files

Tags: 6, performance

I have installed the events and signup modules. The events appears in a calender. All were working fine. But when I enabled the optimizing JS files on the performance page Now the events does not display for the anonymous and authentication user. Now they are only available for the administrator.
I again the disabled the optimizing JS files on performance page but still events are not displaying.

Can someone tell me what is the problem?
I am using drupal 6.

Comment: did any of MPD's suggestions give you more information you could share?

Comment: After enable JS optimization I check the status report there all things are fine, still don't know what is the problem?

Comment: What were the answers to the first two questions below, and specifically whether you can read the JS file when you do a view source?

Answer (score 1):

Give [AdvAgg](http://drupal.org/project/advagg) a try. If JS Aggregation doesn't work, go to admin/reports/status and see what AdvAgg says; it has tests for just about every scenario that would cause JS optimizations to not work.

Answer (score 0):

Is you `sites/default/files` directory writable by the webserver?

If you enable JS opt, view source, do you get valid output when you try to view the JS itself?

Does http://whatever/admin/reports/status list anything unusual?